# add and remove multiple classes in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I have a simple div with an id of #quoteForm and an empty class that get's populated with 2 different classes based on a couple of seperate conditions namely a scroll condition and an innderWidth condition.

Basically what I want to happen is the div  to have the class name .quoteform-fixed after scrolling a little down the page and then the class name .quoteform-hidden added after scrolling but with a innerWidth of 1670px.

This is what I have come up with in vanilla javascript...

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');
  if (top > 800) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-fixed");
  } else if (top > 800 || window.innerWidth < 1670) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-hidden");
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-fixed");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-hidden");
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-fixed");
  }
}
```

What is happening is the .quoteform-hidden is automatically added as soon as I scroll and the second class is also added to the div so after scrolling it looks like this...

```
<div id="quoteForm" class="quoteform-hidden quoteform-fixed"></div>
```

This also happens no matter what size the width of the browser is.
Any ideas?

UPDATE.

Done a bit of thinking and its nearly there. In a browser window with the width above 1670px the javascript adds the class name .quoteform-fixed and of course removes that class as I scroll back to the top.

The problem that occurs is when I shrink the browser window below 1670px because as I scroll the .quoteform-hidden is immediatly added and then as i scroll some more the .quoteform-fixed is also added and both remain populated as I scroll back to the top.

Here is my new code...

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');
  if (top > 800) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-fixed");
  } else if (innerWidth < 1670 || top > 800) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-hidden");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-fixed");
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-hidden");
  }
}
```

Comment: The second condition is essentially `if (!(top > 800) && (top < 800 || innerWidth < 1670)` is that really desired? Maybe that condition should be first?

Comment: I think your if/else are a bit messy, you should only have the need to add/remove 1 class, you have your default state which is coded as is, then add class for the second state when you are in the scrolling area. Add class when you are in range, else remove class.

Comment: @CollinD that helped and just moving a couple of things around helped a lot, thanks fella.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I fixed it with this...

```
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var form = document.getElementById('quoteForm');
  if (top > 800 && innerWidth < 1670) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-hidden");
  } else if (top > 800) {
    form.classList.add("quoteform-fixed");
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-hidden");
  } else {
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-fixed");
    form.classList.remove("quoteform-hidden");
  }
}
```